# Oki Microline 320 printer + network print queues + windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printing, network-printer

We have a Ubuntu database server with raw print queues for multiple connected dot matrix printers (Oki Microlines)

Our software maps these print queues to networked printers installed on the local machine.

Other Windows 7 (32bit) machines have the printer installed as a 'Oki Microline 320 Turbo' and the port pointing to the Database server - //database/raw_p8 and work correctly.

A new machine i've installed is setup the exact same way, yet it prints garbage instead of anything readable. When changing the print driver to 'Generic Text Only' I get readable data but it doesn't line feed. Have tried the updated drivers from the Okidata website aswell as several other types of older printers (other Oki's, HP laserjet 4 and Epson LP).

Any ideas? Pointers? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Using 'Print Management' in Control Panel/Administrative Tools I removed all drivers associated with Oki printers, after first removing them from 'Devices and Printers'. Rebooted then reinstalled the printer by mapping it from the network resource.

It then proceeded to work properly and quickly.